# Transparent background with color of foreground image

Tags: android, css, graphics, material-design, photoshop

Can someone help me with having this sort of transparent background with color of foreground image. Should i use multiple filters of transparent images or how is this achieved i am able to get transparency with `#AARRGGBB` values but not a texture like that shown in the below images.

I am using same foreground image and same background image now i want to introduce a filter between those two so that only color of image is visible not the image itself. I want to know what value(ARGB) of transparent filter should i use in between those two images to achieve this or is there any other approach.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Let's see some code. I am not sure what exactly you want to do. What code have you tried?

Comment: @happymacarts There is nothing to do with code, in my ui i am using transparent background as #AA-00-00-00 with alpha channel as 50% transparent which makes it #80-00-00-00 having which makes my background image visible i want only the color of the foreground image to be visible not the foreground image itself.

Comment: Well since this has nothing to do with code, this may not be the correct place to post a question. If i was answering this question under the photoshop tag i might say just eyedrop the color and create a mask. It looks like its more of a BLUR than an rgba fill

Comment: @happymacarts for your information i am trying to achieve this solution for an android app if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you are looking for [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html).

> It is a helper class to extract prominent colors from an image. A
>   number of colors with different profiles are extracted from the image:
>
> - Vibrant
> - Vibrant Dark
> - Vibrant Light
> - Muted
> - Muted Dark
> - Muted Light

Here, how you use it.

```
 // Synchronous
 Palette p = Palette.from(bitmap).generate();

 // Asynchronous
 Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new PaletteAsyncListener() {
     public void onGenerated(Palette p) {
         // Use generated instance
     }
 });
```

And to retrive the color,

```
p.getVibrantColor(int defaultColor)  //return int of RGB
```

However, `Pallete` returns only one Color, not a Gradient as you have shown in the question images. To me, it seems like they have blurred and added transparency to the foreground image and then posted it in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that there are few easy options to achieve this on android using libraries like [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) or [Picasso transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) both by developer called wasabeef. I used picasso transformations as it seamlessly integrates with picasso image library if you are already using it in your project. All i did was mention the type of transformation i want in this case a blured tansformation and give optional radius and sampling rate.

```
            Picasso
            .with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(imgUrl)
            .transform(new BlurTransformation(imageView.getContext(),10,8))
            .fit()
            .placeholder(placeHolder)
            .error(error)
            .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple solution that may achieve what you are looking for just using CSS no plugins required

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align:right;
}
.wrapper div {
  background-image: url("http://www.placecage.com/c/200/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
  -ms-filter: blur(12px);
  filter: blur(12px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10; /* place below other items*/
}
.focus {
  z-index: 999;/* make sure to place at a high z-index so it shows up on top*/
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="focus"></div>
  <a href="https://www.placecage.com/">Place Cage </a>
</div>
```